# Drop Down Popup Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have an issue with jQuery Popup Drop down. My Issue is When I click the drop down its Opening . Under the Drop Down there are parent and child lists . But when I click on any of the child list its sliding upwards. Again when i try to open the Drop down for the First time is not getting slide down. But second time its getting Slide down. Can anyone Help me out plz ? `Here is My Code :`

```
<script>

function test()
{

jQuery("div[class^='dropDownButton']").slideUp();
}
function test1()
{
jQuery("div[class^='dropDownButton']").slideDown(); 
}
```

Comment: can you update your code in fiddle.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't something CSS can be handling? http://cssdeck.com/labs/another-simple-css3-dropdown-menu

Comment: yea @stanze i can do it but im getting all the data dynamically so its bit difficult to update it in fiddle . Here i can provide you the url of the Drop down which we are using . http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxtree/index.htm#demos/jqxtree/dropdowntree.htm

Comment: In that example when we click on the drop down there it will show all the parent and child lists . when we click on any of the child lists it needs to slide up and slide down. That is my requirement.

Comment: But in the url which i provided there inside the drop down even if we click it s not showing any slide up and slide down event . its showing constant.

Comment: Can you replicate your issue here: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/y5r3w7j3/)